# Is there a way to export a list of all pages and files?

Tags: nodes

I received an email from a customer today requesting a list of all pages and files on their website. Since they are content administrators, I am about to reply with simple instructions for navigating the "Content" area since all the information they are looking for is there.

Is there a module or a tool of sorts that could help generate a list automatically of all the nodes within a site?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
>   data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
>   progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
>   exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV
> - Microsoft XLS (or really simple HTML understood by Excel)
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT
> - XML

and export as CSV. I recommend you watch this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssOF3nPgcfc).

Your client can then view the CSV file in Excel.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! They will be thrilled!